# Rails model namespace and named_helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok... I have a namespaced model `Operations::Expense`.
The resource declaration on routes.rb is 'scoped' 'cause I don't want the path '/operations/expenses' (just '/expenses'):

```
scope module: 'operations' do
  resources :expenses
end
```

The new/edit form:

```
<%= form_for @operation, as: 'operation' %>
```

Where @operation is an Expense object.

The problem is: when I open '/expenses/new', got the error

```
undefined method 'operations_expenses_path'
```

How can I fix that keeping the namespace out of the URL?

P.S.: already tried the `url` option on form_for with `expenses_path(@operation)` but didn't worked...

Comment: It's working for me. Can you show `new`/`edit` method from `Operations::ExpensesController` class?

Comment: [your first routes with `scope module: 'operations'` right and should generate path without prefix just `'/expenses'`.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Comment: What does `rake routes` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails' using model class: `Operations::Expense` to create the routes for `new` and `edit` methods. As it try to use the namespace and convert it into route something like: `operations_expenses_(path/url)`.

Since, you have `scope module: 'operations'`, it creates `expenses_(path/url)` methods instead.

Try changing your routes to this:

```
namespace :operations, path: '/' do
  resources :expenses
end
```

This will create `operations_expenses_(path/url)` helper methods, yet route to `'/expenses'`.

However, providing a url to `form_for` should work just fine(since it worked for me):

For `new` -

```
<%= form_for(@operation, as: 'operation', url: expenses_path, method: :post)) do |f| %>
```

For `edit` -

```
<%= form_for(@operation, as: 'operation', url: expenses_path(@operation), method: :patch)) do |f| %>
```